# Oracle Trigger basic

Tags: oracle, triggers

Not an expert but trying to work with Oracle Triggers.

I wanted to capture previous value before column value in the table gets updated.
Following code works but I wanted to get expert opinion.
There are around 15 tables and some tables have more than one column for which trigger has to be created to capture before update value of the column.
I figured number of columns would dictate number of triggers.

My question is, do you foresee any issue with this code?

```
CREATE TABLE REF_TABLE_MAIN 
(
REF_ID INTEGER,
TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(100),
COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR2(100), 
PRIMARY KEY (REF_ID));

CREATE INDEX REF_TABLE_MAIN_REF_IX ON REF_TABLE_MAIN (REF_ID);

CREATE TABLE RT_LOG
(
    REF_ID INTEGER,
    TXN_REFERENCE_NUMBER VARCHAR2(100),
    PREV_COLUMN_VALUE VARCHAR2(100),
    CURR_UPDATEDBY VARCHAR2(100),
    CREATED_DT DATE,    
    LOAD_DT DATE
);      
CREATE INDEX RT_LOG_CIDX ON RT_LOG (REF_ID, TXN_REFERENCE_NUMBER, CREATED_DT);



CREATE TABLE RT_TXN_DTL
(
    RT_TXN_DTL_ID NUMBER(19),
    TXN_ID NUMBER(19),
    EXPLAIN_CODE VARCHAR2(10),  --This is the column trigger is based on
    EXPLAIN_STATUS VARCHAR2(10),
    VERSION_NUMBER INTEGER(10),
    NOTES VARCHAR2(100),
    CREATED_DT DATE 
);


CREATE TABLE MAIN_TXN_DUMP -- (Around 40 Columns)
(
    TXN_REFERENCE_NUMBER NUMBER(19),
    TXN_ID NUMBER(19),
    COMMENTS VARCHAR2(100),
    CURRNECY_TYPE_CD VARCHAR2(10),
    STATUS_CODE VARCHAR2(10),
    .
    .
    .
    CREATED_DT DATE 
);


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_BEFORE_UPD_RT_TXN_DTL
AFTER UPDATE OF EXPLAIN_CODE ON RT_TXN_DTL
   FOR EACH ROW 

DECLARE 
  v_REF_ID INTEGER; 
  v_TXN_REFERENCE_NUMBER VARCHAR2(100); 
BEGIN 
--Following woud populate Surrogate key value for each column from Reference table.
    SELECT REF_ID INTO v_REF_ID FROM REF_TABLE_MAIN 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME='RT_TXN_DTL' AND COLUMN_NAME='EXPLAIN_CODE';

--Following would populate Reference Number in LOG table for each TXN_ID since Reference Number doesn't currently exist in the table column for which trigger is created. 
    
  SELECT TXN_REFERENCE_NUMBER INTO v_TXN_REFERENCE_NUMBER FROM MAIN_TXN_DUMP 
  WHERE TXN_ID = :NEW.TXN_ID ;
 
   INSERT INTO RT_LOG (REF_ID, TXN_REFERENCE_NUMBER, PREV_COLUMN_VALUE, NEW_UPDATEDBY, CREATED_DT, LOAD_DT ) 
  VALUES(REF_ID, v_TXN_REFERENCE_NUMBER, :OLD.EXPLAIN_CODE, 'X',:OLD.CREATED_DT,SYSDATE) ; 

END;
```

Comment: Your trigger is `AFTER UPDATE OF EXPLAIN_CODE ON RT_TXN_DTL` but you have not provided the code for `RT_TXN_DTL`. I assume that these should have been changed to `AFTER UPDATE OF COLUMN_NAME ON REF_TABLE_MAIN` but its not clear that that is correct. You also `SELECT ... FROM MAIN_TXN_DUMP` but you haven't provided that table.

Comment: @MT0 Sorry, for confusion and not provided DDL for other tables, I've now added DDL for RT_TXN_DTL and MAIN_TXN_DUMP. Trigger statement is correct. Trigger is on column name EXPLAIN_CODE  of table RT_TXN_DTL.